# Convert ArrayList to a JSON file

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of LinkedHashMaps. Now I want to write the Arraylist to a json file as shown below.

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"
        },
        {
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

in  each of the LinkedHashMap I have,

```
{
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2"
}
```

So, I have many of the above type in the ArrayList.

I tried the below code,

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("testfile.json");
jo.put("results", resultList);
p.write(jo.toString());
```

but it doesn't give the exact result I want. It returns a string as below.

```
{"results":"[{key1=value1,key2=value2},{key1=value1,key2=value2}]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me,

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("testfile.json");
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
p.write(om.writeValueAsString(resultList));
p.close();
```

Comment: Please add a description of your code and explain how it solves the problem